# Использовать proxy в PHP с помощью curl

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Хочу подключиться к сайту с помощью curl, но сайт работает только через Америку. Подключаюсь к сайту с помощью curl и proxy.

```
$imei = '867011052411005';
$url = "https://www.cricketwireless.com/restservices/onlineadapter/v1/devices/$imei";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '45.32.231.36:31280');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'login:password');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$errr = curl_error($ch);
var_dump($res); echo '<hr>'; 
var_dump($errr);
```

В итоге к сайту не подключается, в error -> "Received HTTP code 402 from proxy after CONNECT"

Не могу понять в чем проблема, буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/402

Comment: @DanielProtopopov это я и так видел)
Но проблему подключения это никак не решает) \

Comment: проксю проверь, например через свой браузер, мож нерабочая))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логин и пароль прокси проверить

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'login:password');
```